# Taking values associated with each element in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list `a` which has `id, (x,y), err` associated with object detection. So each `id` is associated with an `err`. The value of `err` changes from 0 to 5. What i want to do is to take the `err` associated with each `id` and check if its equal to 0. If `err` is 0, then append that `id` to list `errorfree_id` . I am not able to perform this from the mentioned code. Will it be better to do this using a dictionary? Any help will be appreciated.

```
errorfree_id = []
a = [(1,(50,26),0),(6,(18,29),0),(4,(4,18),1)]
for id, (x,y) , err in a:
    if id in err == 0:
        errorfree_id.append(id)
return errorfree_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `filter` and a `lambda` to do that:

```
errorfree_id = [i[0] for i in filter(lambda (i,_,l): l==0, a)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
errorfree_id = []

a = [(1,(50,26),0), (6,(18,29),0), (4,(4,18),1)]

for i, j, k in a:
    if k == 0:
        errorfree_id.append(i)

errorfree_id  #  [1, 6]
```

However, a list comprehension may be easier to maintain:

```
errorfree_id = [i for i, _, k in a if k == 0]
```

Comment: in this case many people use `_` as a placeholder to indicate unused variables: `[i for i, _, k in a if k == 0]`

Answer (score 1):

You just have an error in your condition:

```
for id, (x,y) , err in a:
    if err == 0:
        errorfree_id.append(id)
```

`if id in err == 0` should be `if err == 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with tuple unpacking:

```
>>> a = [(1,(50,26),0),(6,(18,29),0),(4,(4,18),1)]
>>> [id for id,(x,y),err in a if err==0]
[1, 6]
```